# How can I unbind subviews after navigating to a different view in Backbone.js?

Tags: backbone.js, memory-leaks, backbone-views, backbone-events

I am new to backbone, and I'm trying to fix a memory leak issue. The project I'm working on has a collection of models that is represented by a list. Each model has a submit button. The button navigates the user to a view for the corresponding model that either lets them assign the model's data to a user in the database, or return to the list view. Everything I described so far works as intended, but when the user returns to the list after navigating from a model view and chooses a different model to submit instead, then the old one will be submitted in addition to the one in the current view.

From what I've read, I know this is caused by the old view listening to events that are still bound to it, and I've looked into the various backbone functions (remove, unbind, listenTo, etc) that can be used to deal with these views. However, I've tried the functions in the view file where I believe the leak is coming from and it still doesn't seem to kill the old views. I'm also using a function in the router that removes views before loading another, but it doesn't seem to remove the subviews for the models that were navigated to in the list.

The initialize function, return function, and events for the view generating leaks

```
initialize: function (options) {
    if (!(options && options.model)) {
        throw new Error("No item specified for model");
    }
    if (!options.bus) {
        throw new Error("No bus specified");
    }
    if (!options.router) {
        throw new Error("No router specified");
    }

    this.bus = options.bus;
    this.router = options.router;
    this.listenTo(this.model, "returnToList", this.unbind()); //using unbind here after the return button is clicked
},

events: {
    "click #submit": "submit",
    "click #back": "returnToList"
},

//this function will call a function in the router that creates a view for the collection and then calls the loadView function to remove the old view.
returnToList: function () {
    this.router.navigate("exceptionIndex", { trigger: true });
}
```

This is the function used in the router to remove old views

```
loadView: function (view) {
    if (this._currentView) {
        this._currentView.remove();
    }

    $("#MainContainer").html(view.render().$el);

    this._currentView = view;
}
```

The model view should only submit the model that is being referenced for the view, even if the user previously navigated from other model views. 
The console produces no errors when this issue occurs.

Comment: Is it possible to create an [mcve]?

Comment: Thank you for responding. I'm not sure if I can given that the backbone page is dependent on a cs controller and a database, and the problem view is dependent on other views as well. If this isn't enough to determine the issue, then I guess my question would be: does the given code use the correct function calls that would typically be used to dispose old views? I'm almost certain that the given code is responsible for the leak, but if I'm doing everything correctly, it would help greatly in determining what's actually causing the issue. Thanks again, and sorry I couldn't provide more.

Comment: Yes you are using `listenTo` and then `remove`, which should unbind stuff properly. Probably something sneaky going on elsewhere

Comment: It could be something like - a modal library takes certain DOM outside of the view's el, to append it to body (some modals do that)  so `remove` can no longer clean it up :philiosoraptor: In such case you should be using the modal libraries destruction/cleanup methods. Just an example

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying. Thank you, you've given me something to look into now.

Comment: careful in `this.listenTo(this.model, "returnToList", this.unbind())`, you probably want `this.unbind` instead of `this.unbind()`. You want to pass the function itself, not its return value.